# How to rename a compiled sass file in a Gulp task

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to write a simple gulp task that takes a scss file called manifest.scss and after compiling and minifying the file it saves the result into a destination folder as app.css

The following task does almost everything I want beside renaming the file (the output is build/css/manifest.css)

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
 gulp.src("src/sass/manifest.scss")
      .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed' }))
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

So, I have tried gulp-rename and I have update the task as follows:

```
gulp.task('sass',  function() {
 gulp.src("src/sass/manifest.scss")
      .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed' }))
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
      .pipe(rename('app.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

This produces the build/css/app.css file but it is totally blank.

How can I rename the compiled file?

Thanks

Comment: That looks correct. Does the first example generate non-empty file?

Comment: Yep, seems fine to me too, have you tried using only the `basename` option ?

Comment: Yes it generates an empty file.

@Aperçu where should I put ```basename```?  Thanks

Comment: If the first example generates an empty file, there is no problem because what you did will work, try to put something in your sass file.

Comment: manifest.scss has several code inside. and if I remove the rename line the generated manifest.css contains all the supposed code. The issue is with the renaming.

Comment: So the generated file from the first example is not empty.. Is minifyCSS this one? -> [gulp-minify-css](https://github.com/jonathanepollack/gulp-minify-css)

Comment: the first example is not empty. yes I use gulp-minify-css